# Why do I get "Composite Literal Uses Unkeyed" error?

Tags: go, struct, literals

I'm relatively new to Go and am working on building out a request decoder. The request comes in JSON format and we decode that to a map[string]interface{}. We then pass that object data in to be decoded to our own ProcessRequest struct. As I said I'm new so I am reusing some logic in similar parts of the code wrote by previous developers. Essentially we are checking the map for the necessary pieces and then setting and returning those. Can someone explain to me why I am getting the titled error? Would I have to set the items all the way down to base structs that no longer have any nested? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want? Here is the code and the related structs. It is highlighting the error on the return of the model.ProcessRequest. TYIA

```
type ProcessRequest struct {
    RequestID string
    Message   *message.Message
    Rule      *Rule
    Options   *ProcessOptions
    //TODO: Context EvaluatorContext
    //TODO: Links
}

type Message struct {
    ID         int
    Key        string
    Source     string
    Headers    *HeaderSet
    Categories *CategorySet
    Properties *PropertySet
    Streams    *StreamSet
}

type RuleAction struct {
    Name       string
    Expression map[string]interface{}
}

type RuleLink struct {
    LinkID       int
    Condition    map[string]interface{}
    TargetRuleID int
}

type Rule struct {
    Name    string
    Code    string
    Actions []RuleAction
    Links   []RuleLink
}
type object = map[string]interface{}

func DecodeProcessRequest(dataObject map[string]interface{}) (*model.ProcessRequest, error) {
    var (
        requestID string
        message   *message.Message
        rule      *model.Rule
        options   *model.ProcessOptions
        err       error
    )

    if reqIDSrc, ok := dataObject["requestId"]; ok {
        if requestID, err = converter.ToString(reqIDSrc); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Error reading property 'requestID'")
        }
        if requestID == "" {
            return nil, errors.Errorf("Property 'requestID' is an empty string")
        }
    } else {
        return nil, errors.Errorf("Missing required property 'requestID'")
    }

    if messageSrc, ok := dataObject["message"]; ok {
        messageData, ok := messageSrc.(object)
        if !ok {
            return nil, errors.Errorf("Error reading property 'message': Value is not an object")
        }
        if message, err = DecodeMessage(messageData); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Error reading property 'message'")
        }
    } else {
        return nil, errors.Errorf("Missing required property 'message'")
    }

    if ruleSrc, ok := dataObject["rule"]; ok {
        ruleObj, ok := ruleSrc.(object)
        if !ok {
            return nil, errors.Errorf("Error reading property 'rule': Value is not an object")
        }
        if rule, err = DecodeRule(ruleObj); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Error reading 'rule' during decoding")
        }
    } else {
        return nil, errors.Errorf("Missing required property 'requestID'")
    }
    // Parse plain object to a Message struct
    return &model.ProcessRequest{
        requestID,
        message,
        rule,
        options,
    }, nil

}
```

Comment: Please include the error message in the question, and show what part of the code produces the error. Also it's always a good idea to remove as much of the code as possible. Only keep as little code as you need to reproduce the error. Have a look at how to make a [mre].

Comment: In general, the warning says that you should prefer to use the syntax `ProcessRequest{ RequestID: requestID, ... }`. Naming the keys instead of unkeyed values.

Comment: Some of the `struct`s values of which you're trying to construct using [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) contains a field with the name `_` (a sole underline). This makes the compiler reject the definition—unless you use `FieldName: fieldValue` notation to set field values. This is sort of a hack intended to make such literals resilient to changes in the order of the fields in the definition of such `struct` types.

Comment: Thank you adding in the RequestID: requestID solved the error. I can't mark this as an answer though for some reason?

Comment: Basically the idea is that if you use "unkeyed" way of defining struct literals, the _meaning_ of your definitions depends on the way the fields of the underlying type are layed out. Now consider that your type has three fields of type `string` in a certain order. Now a couple of iterations down the road some programmer moves the second field to the 1st position—your literal will still compile but will end up defining a completely different value at runtime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super) said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498491/why-do-i-get-composite-literal-uses-unkeyed-error/71498702#comment126371732_71498491):

> In general, the warning says that you should prefer to use the syntax `ProcessRequest{ RequestID: requestID, ... }`. Naming the keys instead of unkeyed values.

That worked for me. Also the explanation by [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498491/why-do-i-get-composite-literal-uses-unkeyed-error/71498702#comment126371866_71498491) really helped.

> Basically the idea is that if you use "unkeyed" way of defining struct literals, the meaning of your definitions depends on the way the fields of the underlying type are layed out. Now consider that your type has three fields of type `string` in a certain order. Now a couple of iterations down the road some programmer moves the second field to the 1st position—your literal will still compile but will end up defining a completely different value at runtime.